# PowerPC reversing finding the SDA and the TOC

Tags: ida, powerpc

For PowerPCs how do you find out the TOC address or the SDA address? 
Like for example in this [case](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13923/how-to-dissassemble-motorola-freescale-nxp-powerquicc-excutable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SDA` is `r13`, and it changes very rarely. So finding any assignment to r13 will solve the problem for SDA.

Specifically for the referred example it was

```
lis       r13, 1        # Load Immediate Shifted
addi      r13, r13, -0x2BF0 # 0xD410 # Add Immediate
```

Comment: Thanks! About the TOC any hint?

Comment: @amgnet: same but with r2 instead of r13

Comment: Thank you. I noticed more r2 loading references than r13 which is clearly one or 2 maximum. I would assume it should be also nearby? Is this the Global TOC right ?